# Android registration and login using MySQL

Tags: android, sql, xml, json, sqlite

I'm working on an Android App, and I stuck with the function of user registration and log-in.

I need to store the information on MySQL DB.

Now I have I code this function but it is not running. I have a errors which I could not figure it out.

Here is my main java file:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;

public class DashboardActivity extends Activity {
UserFunctions userFunctions;
Button btnLogout;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Dashboard Screen for the application
     * */        
    // Check login status in database
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                userFunctions.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                // Closing dashboard screen
                finish();
            }
        });

    }else{
        // user is not logged in show login screen
        Intent login = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(login);
        // Closing dashboard screen
        finish();
    }




}}
```

my registration function

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);

    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

my Log-in

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.util.HashMap;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
Button btnLogin;
Button btnLinkToRegister;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView loginErrorMsg;

// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
    loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            Log.d("Button", "Login");
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(email, password);

            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS); 
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        // Close Login Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText("Incorrect username/password");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}}
```

my Database Handler

```
package com.example.androidhive.library;

import java.util.HashMap;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

  public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

// Login table name
private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

// Login Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
            + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * Storing user details in database
 * */
public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
    values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
    values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

/**
 * Getting user data from database
 * */
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}

/**
 * Getting user login status
 * return true if rows are there in table
 * */
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
    db.close();
    cursor.close();

    // return row count
    return rowCount;
}

/**
 * Re crate database
 * Delete all tables and create them again
 * */
public void resetTables(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // Delete All Rows
    db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
    db.close();
}}
```

My JSON Parser

```
package com.example.androidhive.library;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);            
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}}
```

UserFUnctions

```
package com.example.androidhive.library;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;

public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/ah_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";

// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    // Log.e("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}}
```

and finally here comes my erro Logcat:

```
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0    Strict//EN"
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <head>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <title>Object not found!</title>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <link rev="made" href="mailto:postmaster@localhost" />
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <style type="text/css"><!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/ 
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):     body { color: #000000; background-color: #FFFFFF;  }
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):     a:link { color: #0000CC; }
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):     p, address {margin-left: 3em;}
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):     span {font-size: smaller;}
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): /*]]>*/--></style>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): </head>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <body>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <h1>Object not found!</h1>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <p>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):     The requested URL was not found on this server.
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):   
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):     If you entered the URL manually please check your
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):     spelling and try again.
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):   
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): </p>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <p>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): If you think this is a server error, please contact
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): the <a href="mailto:postmaster@localhost">webmaster</a>.
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): </p>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <h2>Error 404</h2>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): <address>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):   <a href="/">10.0.2.2</a><br />
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388):   <span>Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7</span>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): </address>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): </body>
02-12 14:11:09.267: E/JSON(388): </html>
02-12 14:11:09.408: E/JSON Parser(388): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.example.androidhive.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:64)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-12 14:11:09.477: E/AndroidRuntime(388):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeMethod)
```

I really need a help as this is my final year project and I stuck with this connection for months :O

so you cooperation is much appreciated thanks anyway guys  please do your best to guide me

Comment: It appears that you have posted code from complete application. Please point out to the actual problem that you might be facing to actually let us help.

Comment: yes coz I thought it's better to post the whole stuff so it's the pic.is clear to troubleshoot my problem appears in mylogcat that I included

Comment: For one, you have a NullPointerException coming from line 64 in your RegisterActivity. You are also trying to assign a java.lang.String as a JSONObject. Have you tried stepping through with a debugger to see what's null / what you're trying to operate on as a JSONObject?

Comment: @user1794499 : make sure u have HttpPost request or HttpGet ? try `HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);`

Comment: I debug the app. and it higlights me this line  if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {    it's located the registeractivity.java

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K but I do have a httppost in my JSONParser.java in the getJSONFromUrl method.....would you please have a look at it

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing the logcat, there appears to be two problems:

1. The requested URL was not found, that its an HTTP 404
2. You are trying to convert the received response from the http server to a Json Object. In this case since the URL was not found the server has returned an XML structure and hence can't be converted to a Json Object.

These are very first problems that you'd need to address.

Comment: okaaay, so how can solve these two issues?can you please help me further

Comment: First one is simple, you need to make sure the URL that you are requesting is valid and accepts and returns valid data as your program  expects. For second one, you need to make sure you translate returned data to jsonObject only when you are sure that it is valid json data.